# Creating a new list by dropping sub elements of the original list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Suppose I have a nested listed as follows,

```
{{{1,2},{3,4,5},{2,3}},{{2,3,4},{5,4,1},{1,4,3}},{{3,4,5},{3,4,5}}}
```

Where the elements are,

> ```
> {{1,2},{3,4,5},{2,3}}
>
> {{2,3,4},{5,4,1},{1,4,3}}
>
> {{3,4,5},{3,4,5}}
> ```

I would I create a new list where I drop any sub element that has 1 or 2 in its first part.  The output should then look like this,

> ```
> {{{3,4,5}},{{5,4,1}},{{3,4,5},{3,4,5}}}
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 lst = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 4, 1}, {1, 4,  3}}, 
        {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}};

 Select[#, FreeQ[#[[1]], 1 | 2] &] & /@ lst
```

or

```
 Pick[#, FreeQ[#[[1]], 1 | 2] & /@ #] & /@ lst
```

or

```
 Cases[#, _?(FreeQ[#[[1]], 1 | 2] &)] & /@ lst
```

or

```
 DeleteCases[#, _?(! FreeQ[#[[1]], 1 | 2] &)] & /@ lst
```

all give

```
{{3, 4, 5}}, {{5, 4, 1}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}}
```

Comment: @Ibrahim, you might want to wait a while before accepting an answer to encourage alternative answers. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: @RunnyKine, thank you.. "almost" is critical :)

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 3}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}}
```

Then:

```
Cases[{Except[1 | 2], __}] /@ list  (* v10 syntax *)
```

> `{{{3, 4, 5}}, {{5, 4, 1}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}}`

OR

```
Map[Cases[{Except[1 | 2], __}]]@list  (* v10 operator form *)
```

OR

```
Select[#, #[[1]] != 1 && #[[1]] != 2 &] & /@ list
```

OR

```
Select[#[[1]] != 1 && #[[1]] != 2 &] /@ list  (* v10 syntax *)
```

Comment: Indeed, a subtle but significant change between V9 and V10. How did you discover it? Is it in the documentation?

Comment: @eldo. Yes it's in the documentation, I believe that's where I learned it.

Answer (score 2):

[`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeleteCases.html) with *levelspec*:

```
expr = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 3}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}};

DeleteCases[expr, {1 | 2, __}, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{{3, 4, 5}}, {{5, 4, 1}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}}
> ```

Or, inspired by RunnyKine's answer, in v10 operator syntax:

```
DeleteCases[{1 | 2, __}] /@ expr
```

> ```
> {{{3, 4, 5}}, {{5, 4, 1}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}}
> ```

Comment: +1 I tried using *levelspec* but kept botching it

Comment: @RunnyKine I like your use of the operator syntax, by the way. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'm really liking the new operator forms. :)

Comment: @RunnyKine I just use `Infinity` because I'm lazy.

Comment: @seismatica That's fine, but be aware that it can come at a significant cost to performance.  Most of the time not, but sometimes.  Starting perhaps a year and a half ago I try to be more specific with my use of *levelspec*.

Answer (score 1):

Since all the good answers have been given, here's a dumb one:

```
expr = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 3}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}};
expr //. {pre___, {1 | 2, ___}, post___} :> {pre, post}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the list is all numbers, here's another way:

```
list = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 3}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}};
drop = {1, 2};

Pick[list, 
 Unitize[
    Evaluate[Times @@ (# - drop)] & @
     Map[
      First,
      list,
      {2}]
  ],
 1
 ]
(*
  {{{3, 4, 5}}, {{5, 4, 1}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}}
*)
```

Edit: changed the function applied to `Map` (thanks, Mr.Wizard), which originally was

```
Evaluate[ReleaseHold @ Fold[#1 (Hold[Slot][1] - #2) &, 1, drop]] &
```

Comment: That's a twisted use of `Hold[Slot]`, sure to confuse half the people who read this, and really quite unnecessary as well. Naturally, +1. :D

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I guess so, or I'm getting tired.  BTW, I tried `Inactive` but it was slower than `Hold`, I think just by a constant (not depending on `list`).  Not sure why.  Maybe I'll fix the `Hold`... :)

Comment: Really I figured it was intentional obfuscation.  Can't you just write `Evaluate[Times @@ (# - drop)] &`?  Or maybe *I'm* tired.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, I think it's me who's tired.  I started with something else that morphed while my brain wore out.  Thanks for the simple code.

Comment: Ah, one of *those* sessions.  Say no more. :o)

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {2, 3}},
        {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 3}},
        {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}};
```

---

Using `Replace` at level `2`:

```
Replace[list, {1 | 2, __} :> Nothing, {2}]

(*{{{3, 4, 5}}, {{5, 4, 1}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}}*)
```

Or using `Position` and `Delete`:

```
Delete[#, Position[#, x_List /; ! FreeQ[x[[1]], 1 | 2], {2}]] &@list

(*{{{3, 4, 5}}, {{5, 4, 1}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list =
 {{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {2, 3}}, 
  {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 3}}, 
  {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}};
```

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[list, {1 | 2, __} :> Nothing, {;; , ;;}]
```

{{{3, 4, 5}}, {{5, 4, 1}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}}

Using function deconstruction

```
f[{1 | 2, __}] := Nothing

f[a_] := a

Map[f, list, {2}]
```

{{{3, 4, 5}}, {{5, 4, 1}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 
     3}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}};

f = First@# =!= 1 && First@# =!= 2 &;

Select[#, f] & /@ list
DeleteCases[list, _?(Not@*f), {2}]
Map[f, list, {2}] // Pick[list, #] &
```

---

> {{{3, 4, 5}}, {{5, 4, 1}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}}}